# C# Passing Socket Connections between computers

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm looking for a simple way to mock up an arbitration application for testing purposes.  The idea is to create three separate nodes (On three different computers), these nodes will work as clients to a C# server socket I'm testing.  Lets say I'm trying to set up 4 client-server connections, I'd like the arbiter to determine randomly which node gets which connections.  If one of the nodes dies (the application is shutdown) I'd like the arbiter to pass its connections to another node.  When a node is turned back on I'd like the arbiter to redistribute the connections.  Any links or example code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: The actual socket connections are tied to the machine that made them, but you could have an abstraction of a connection in the arbiter and keep an inventory of who got what that you can then redistribute when a node goes down.

Comment: The idea of a client connection migrating when the client goes down is very strange.  Maybe you'd do that in a failover cluster, but it sounds like you're talking about something else.

Answer (score 0):

Socket connections don't work that way - they are created between two machines.  The good news is that the cost of creating a new connection is not significant.

It's probably worth it to read up on [Berkely Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) if you want to learn about how you can work with them in detail.

Unless you mean that you don't care about actual connection objects, but rather about the total number of connections.  In that case what you can use is a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) or [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) to control the total number of connections.  That will allow you to distribute connections randomly until you hit a maximum number.  Then, when connections are lost, you redistribute again until the semaphore is maxed out; when a new client connects, you can perform the reverse process - close connections to random current clients and open new ones to the new client until the number is balanced to your liking.

Let me know if that's what you had in mind - I don't want to get too far into it if you were thinking of something else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really "pass" sockets between computers. When you create them, the TCP/IP stack allocates all kinds of settings that cannot be transferred, such as TCP sequence numbers and such. What you can do however is keep your "Arbiter" alive with all incoming connections. The arbiter will then create another socket to your nodes so that it will act as a proxy between the two.

You should look up load balancing general architectures, this is quite what you want I think